# Do I need to update my domain nameservers for each Terraform run?

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns

I've followed the instructions here - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/migrate-dns-domain-in-use.html - for pointing my domain at Route 53 servers.

I then have a terraform script which works properly (except for the issue I'm about to discuss):

```
provider "aws" {
  access_key = var.access_key
  secret_key = var.secret_key
  region     = var.region
}

module "networkModule" {
  source            = "./modules/network"
  access_key        = var.access_key
  secret_key        = var.secret_key
  region            = var.region
  app_tag           = var.app_tag
  availability_zone = var.availability_zone
  public_key_path   = var.public_key_path
}

module "securityGroupModule" {
  source     = "./modules/securityGroup"
  access_key = var.access_key
  secret_key = var.secret_key
  region     = var.region
  vpc_id     = module.networkModule.vpc_id
  app_tag    = var.app_tag
}

module "instanceModule" {
  source             = "./modules/instance"
  access_key         = var.access_key
  secret_key         = var.secret_key
  region             = var.region
  instance_type      = var.instance_type
  instance_ami       = var.instance_ami
  vpc_id             = module.networkModule.vpc_id
  subnet_public_id   = module.networkModule.public_subnets[0]
  key_pair_name      = module.networkModule.ec2keyName
  security_group_ids = ["${module.securityGroupModule.sg_22}", "${module.securityGroupModule.sg_80}"]
  app_tag            = var.app_tag
}

module "dnsModule" {
  source      = "./modules/dns"
  access_key  = var.access_key
  secret_key  = var.secret_key
  region      = var.region
  domain_name = "pintura.cloud"
  aRecords = [
    "pintura.cloud ${module.instanceModule.instance_eip}",
  ]
  cnameRecords = [
    "www.pintura.cloud pintura.cloud"
  ]
}
```

These are custom modules, but pretty straightforward stuff.

For every time I run this, AWS spits out different name servers. EG

```
base_domain_nameservers = tolist([
  "ns-1215.awsdns-23.org",
  "ns-1857.awsdns-40.co.uk",
  "ns-325.awsdns-40.com",
  "ns-870.awsdns-44.net",
])
```

Do I need to update my hosted domain provider (which is not AWS) each time with these? Or does once work?

Comment: Is it actually changing or just a reorder of the same list? If the latter, just sort the list.

Comment: No, they're new every time I delete and recreate. Just now, they were: base_domain_nameservers = tolist([
  "ns-1440.awsdns-52.org",
  "ns-1739.awsdns-25.co.uk",
  "ns-249.awsdns-31.com",
  "ns-605.awsdns-11.net",
])

Comment: This is correct if you are deleting and recreating, but I am not sure why you would do that repeatedly.

Comment: The need for this resource is highly dynamic and very costly. We’d rather tear it down each time - it’s fine for our scenario.

Comment: I would consider moving out the hosted zone creation as DNS nameservers often have a long TTL and the cost for having it is $0.50/mo.

Comment: Interesting - so just breaking up the dns creation out of here and make that more table would be enough? What’s the easiet way to have AWS DNS servers point at a changing VM? Think a spot instance.

Comment: Using `aws_route53_record` resource. You can use this resource from a different module than you use to create the hosted zone, looking up [the hosted zone id with a data block](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/data-sources/route53_zone) if needed.